# When we assume every set is well-orderable under choice, are we fixing a particular well-order for each set?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

Forgive me if this is a silly question. I am a little stuck on a definition from Kunen's text.

He says:

> **Definition 10.3.** If $A$ can be well-ordered, $|A|$ is the least $\alpha$ in bijection with $A$.

My confusion is as follows: If we assume choice, then every set is well-orderable. i.e. for all $x$ there exists $\alpha$ in bijection with $x$, such that the bijection is moreover an order isomorphism. However, it seems to me then, that choice acts as a class function on $\mathbf{V}$ assigning to each set an order-type from those ordinals in bijection with it, guaranteeing also that there is at least one such ordinal. Otherwise, I think Kunen's definition is pointless, for otherwise we may always select the order-type of $x$ to be the least ordinal in bijection with it and then just set the cardinality to be the order type naturally induced by the aforementioned bijection.

Is this a correct way of viewing choice? Or am I muddling something up?

Comment: The existence of a bijection with *any* ordinal is equivalent to being well-orderable: if you are well-orderable, then there is an ordinal you are in bijection with. If there is an ordinal you are in bijection with, then you can use any such bijection to define a well-ordering by transport of structure. The definition defines "cardinal of $A$", but it only applies to sets $A$ for which $\{\alpha\in\mathrm{Ord}\mid A\text{ can be put in bijection with }\alpha\}$ is nonempty. Choice does not define a class function; AC only applies to families, not classes.

Comment: I will add that there exists an axiom called "global choice" which state exactly that you can have a choice function for classes of sets, in particular you have a way to fix well ordering for all of the sets simultaneously. GC is strictly stronger than AC (in languages that can express it)

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ **is** well-ordered, then we have a unique ordinal which is its order type, and in fact there is a unique bijection which is an order isomorphism. Otherwise, it *can* be, but then it may have many different order types (in fact, if $A$ is infinite, it is exactly what is going to happen).

Moreover, even if you fix one bijection between $A$ and *some* ordinal, we can apply permutations of $A$ or permutations of the ordinal to get different bijections. So there are many different bijections possible. Which one do we use? It isn't clear.

To see a similar situation, note that there is no canonical way to choose *how* to enumerate each countable subset of $\Bbb R$, unless of course we well-ordered $\Bbb R$ and choose an enumeration for each countable ordinal, and then used that to argue that each countable set is isomorphic to a unique countable ordinal (as a subset of our fixed well-order), and now appeal to the bijection we chose between that ordinal and $\omega$.

And indeed, without the axiom of choice, it may very well be that we just cannot make these choices, and even though every countable subset of $\Bbb R$ is well-orderable (indeed, it is countable!), we still cannot assign them all, at the same time, bijections with $\omega$.

The same holds in the case of proper classes and "just $\sf ZFC$". In other words, it is quite possible for a model of $\sf ZFC$ to exist in which there is no definable way to assign a well-ordering to each set. This is exactly the situation when the Axiom of Global Choice fails.